# how to connect an external camera to a custom android app

Tags: android, android-studio, android-camera

i am developing an android app that can detect traffic signs in real time. for better accuracy and detection, i want to use an external camera (probably gopro or any other speed camera) instead of the built in camera of my phone. is there any way to do that? is it possible?

i tried using the camera api but it didn’t work.

Comment: The camera API is going to only work with the built in cameras, not with some random hardware you attach.  If you're buying a camera that's meant for automated use (vs a consumer point and click type thing) it should have an API you would use to control it.  This will likely be specific to the device.  For example, here is GoPro's library  https://gopro.com/en/us/info/open-gopro

Answer (score 0):

please take a look it may work

https://developer.sony.com/cameras/